# Can't get function arguments in assembly program

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64

I am trying to print floats in x86 assembly, I have made a function to print floats and it takes in 2 arguments. However when the function runs and tries to get the arguments, it gets garbage values and the stack pointer doesn't end up in the same place afterwards, resulting in the function not returning properly.

The function:

```
PrintFloat:

    add rsp, 8  ;Getting past the return address and to the arguments

    pop rax     ;rax points to the float
    pop rdx     ;rdx points to the format to print with

    sub rsp, 24 ;Get back to the return address, for some reason doesn't bring rsp back to where it started

    sub rsp,8  ;reserve stack for a double in stack
    fld dword [rax]   ;load float
    fstp qword [rsp]  ;store double (8087 does the conversion internally)
    push rdx
    call _printf
    add rsp, 12

    ret
```

I have tried manually setting the value of rsp back to what if was at the start of the function, which makes the function return properly but it still gets random values from the arguments. I have tried passing the values into the registers in the caller and then not trying to get the arguments in the PrintFloat function, however that still gives random values for some reason.

EDIT:

I have tried using 32 bit instead and instead add 4 to esp, then later subtract 12 from esp, and the function worked just fine. However when using 64 bits it stops working.

Comment: Just a tip: When unsure about the architecture - stack growing/decreasing, C-decl function call convention, float passed as double. either search docs and examples, or better try things piece-wise. 1) a printf with hard coded float, 2) passed, 3) returned, 4) float/double.

Comment: I have tried working with hard coded floats and it worked perfectly, but as soon as I try using arguments it starts printing random characters. I know that the return address should use 8 bytes, same with every argument on the stack.

Comment: x86-64 passes floats in xmm registers. Consult calling convention documentation. Also, don't do that to the poor stack pointer.

Comment: Notwithstanding the other errors, shouldn't  the final `add rsp, 12` `ret` be adding 16 instead (8 bytes from `push rdx` and 8 bytes from `sub rsp, 8`).